# How to make Travis CI test package for Linux, OS X, Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, travis-ci

Is there a way to tell Travis CI (or another continuous integration service) to test the package on different operating systems?

Working with the filesystem, and it would be great to double-check it's all platform-agnostic.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### Update 3

Windows support has been released! You can now use Travis CI with Linux, macOS, and Windows. You can find their blog post about it [here](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-10-11-windows-early-release).

#### Update 2

This feature is enabled now (no need to send request to Travis team). Though still considered beta:

- [Multi-OS](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-os/)

Works fine for me, here is Linux + OSX configuration:

- [.travis.yml](https://github.com/forexample/hunter-simple/blob/ba0e6406a600ef0d41c68746ac0ae74a11abb4e7/.travis.yml)
- [build matrix](https://travis-ci.org/forexample/hunter-simple/builds/105832055)

Windows support still in progress (see [windows issues](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Awindows+)) as alternative [AppVeyor](http://appveyor.com) can be used. Example of configuration file:

- [appveyor.yml](https://github.com/forexample/hunter-simple/blob/ba0e6406a600ef0d41c68746ac0ae74a11abb4e7/appveyor.yml)

#### Update

- [Multi-OS beta testing](http://blog.travis-ci.com/2014-05-13-multi-os-feature-available/)

---

There is an open issue for [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/):

- [Issue #216](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/216)

As a workaround for `Linux` + `Mac OS X` you can create two branches. One with default config (for `Linux`) and one with `objective-c` language (for `Mac OS X`).

Comment: Support for Windows appears to unfortunately have stalled. "As for Windows, we do have ideas on it, and once we know more, we'll update this ticket." was written in 2015.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for a working, Windows/Mac/Linux python configuration example, see this repository: https://github.com/cclauss/Travis-CI-Python-on-three-OSes