# pass env variables to travis specific to deployment

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

i have the following .travis.yaml file:

```
branches:
  only:
    - master
    - develop
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "7.9.0"
script:
  - make build
deploy:
  - provider: s3
    local_dir: build
    acl: public_read
    skip_cleanup: true
    bucket: "app-dev-us-east-1"
    region: "us-east-1"
    on:
      branch: develop
  - provider: s3
    local_dir: build
    acl: public_read
    skip_cleanup: true
    bucket: "app-prod-us-east-1"
    region: "us-east-1"
    on:
      branch: master
```

in my script: make build, what is the correct way to pass a different env variable based on the branch that is being built?

or do i have to modify my makefile and pull the TRAVIS_BRANCH and use that?

any advise is much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Travis CI testing branches with corresponding set of environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099377/travis-ci-testing-branches-with-corresponding-set-of-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this question was already [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099377/travis-ci-testing-branches-with-corresponding-set-of-environment-variables).

One of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22164528/2018369) says that you can have different `.travis.yml` on each branch. However the issue would be with merging between those branches. But you can always add `.travis.yml` to `.gitignore` to ignore these differences during merge.